# Glitches on d3 graph

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have the following graph:
[image]

There are few modifications I would like to make, but can't seem to find how to do it.

1. have the "tick lines" appear inside the graph, meaning right of the y-axis and top of the x-axis (the ones on x-axis are not showing at all), by tick lines I mean the small lines which appear next to t2he value)
2. show the last tick, 2500 in this case as well
3. fix the order of the items, in the screen its being shown correctly, because I reversed the values in the [CSV file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ESaasK0v), and the actual code that draws the graph is the same as in this link: http://www.danielepennati.com/d3/linea2.html (I link to this since I couldn't set up a jsfiddle with the CSV file loading). On that link the tsv file is also in reversed order and the last item from the list is being drawn as first

For the 1., here is the code for axes, so I am already specifying tick values:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y).tickValues([0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000])
  .orient("left");
```

For the 3., I used the sorting in the `d3.csv` handler:

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {return b.date-a.date;});
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) Use `.orient("right")` for the y and `.orient("top")` for the x axis. 2) Use `.tickValues()` to explicitly specify which ticks are shown. 3) Order the data before passing it to D3.

Comment: I have added an edit. 1) The effect on y axis moves the numbers a well, I would need those to remain left, but only those small ticks on the right. There was no change on x axis at all when changing `bottom` to `top`. 2) I have already specified `.tickValues()` but the larger ones are not being shown.

Comment: To have ticks and labels in different orientations, you'd have to combine two axes somehow. The `.tickValues()` method should work, so maybe you're overwriting this somewhere else?

Comment: Two axes sounds complicated :D Is there at least a way to add ticks to the x-axis, since those are not being shown? As I said, I sligthyl modified [this](http://www.danielepennati.com/d3/linea2.html) code, so you can see there what is wrong with x axis. I can't seem to find any overwrite for tick values, they are being applied correctly, If I leave them out they go in increments by 200, but the larger ones are not being shown.

Comment: Using `.tickValues()` is the way to specify which tick values you want.

Comment: I see, lets consider that finished as well, I will update my question. The remaining are the small lines on x-axis, those would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "small lines on x axis"?

Comment: These small lines next to numbers on y axis. http://pokit.org/get/?a2a85abab93d3d837a649721ca66e8f1.jpg They are not present on x axis.

Comment: Hmm, that example doesn't seem to use the axis component to add the labels. Perhaps it would be better to start with a more "canonical" example, e.g.  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245